# Dúvidas com método DAO

Tags: java, testes-de-unidade

Estou com uma dúvida na questão de um DAO genérico, sendo usado em um projeto de testes com Vraptor.

Este dao, funciona normal nos meus requests, mais ao ser usado em um teste unitário o mesmo da o seguinte problema ao tentar remover:

```
@Before
public void init(){
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TEST");
    EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();

    this.dao = new DaoMaster(manager);
}

@Test
public void refusePersistDuplicateDomain(){ 
    Company c1 = new Company("Name", "teste");
    Company c2 = new Company("Name", "teste");

    Assert.assertTrue(this.dao.persist(c1));

    Assert.assertFalse(this.dao.persist(c2));

    this.dao.remove(c1.getId(), Company.class);
}
```

O mesmo gera o seguinte erro ao fazer a remoção do objeto.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: attempt to create delete event with null entity
at org.hibernate.event.spi.DeleteEvent.<init>(DeleteEvent.java:48)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:896)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.remove(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
at br.com.adapcon.jpro.dao.DaoMaster.remove(DaoMaster.java:96)
at br.com.adapcon.jpro.test.dao.CompanyDaoTest.refusePersistDuplicateDomain(CompanyDaoTest.java:65)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.ExpectException.evaluate(ExpectException.java:19)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Esses são os dois métodos usados.

```
public boolean persist(IEntity o){
    try{
        this.charger();
        if (o.getId() != null && o.getId() > 0) {
            manager.merge(o);
        } else {
            manager.persist(o);
        }
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
        return true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean remove(Long id, Class<?> objectClass){
    try{
        this.charger();
        Object o = findById(id, objectClass);
        System.out.println("M: "+id);
        manager.remove(o);
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
        return true;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

private void charger(){
    if(!manager.getTransaction().isActive()){
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
    }
}
```

Comment: Não responde a pergunta, mas dá uma olhada [**aqui**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33916732#33916732).

Answer (score 2):

Realmente, testes de integração não deveriam estar sendo executados na base mas com algum banco de dados em memória, mas o problema pode ser porque você precisa fazer um refresh da [entityManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#refresh-java.lang.Object-) para cada entidade persistida antes de realizar o delete, ex:

> Atualize o estado da instância do banco de dados, substituindo as
>   alterações feitas à entidade, se houver.

```
em.refresh(c1);
```

Exemplo de configuração do banco de dados em memória.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="minhaUnidadePersistencia-test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>br.com.suaApp.SuaEntidade</class>
        ..... demais entidades
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:meuDataBase-test" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: Dilnei, qual o tipo de banco em memória posso usar em conjunto com o hibernate? Gostaria que o hibernate criasse o banco para mim como cria no banco de dados real.

Vi que tem alguns feitos junto a um XML inicial, mais o schema não seria no caso construido pelo próprio hibernate, ou seria?

Comment: Hoje em dia tem de [vários sabores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_in-memory_databases) eu gosto do hsqldb, editei a resposta e adicionei meu persistence.xml para você ver, e pode sim ser com arquivos xml, direto no código ou deixar o Hibernate criar.  
lembrando que o persistence fica na estrutura de test ex: src/test/resources/META-INF